# Several functions in one file: can doxygen document them separately?

Tags: doxygen

General question: If I have several functions in the same file, can `doxygen` document them separately?  For instance, if I have the following *in a single file* is there a tag to add which creates separate documentation for each function?  This option, if it exists, is strangely hard to find.  I'd rather not break out several closely related functions into separate files if I can avoid it.

If I run `doxygen` using the default settings on the contents below in a single file the documentation sections are merged together, as shown below the code.

```
/**
 * @file
 * @brief Some Function 
 * */

void func1(int arg) {
// do something
}

/**
 * @file
 * @brief Some Other Function 
 * */

void func2(int arg) {
// do something
}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd hope if there is a way one could also apply it to multiple structs defined in a single file.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? It looks like you misunderstood the usage of the `@file` command as this "Indicates that a comment block contains documentation for a source or header file with name <name>." (see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdfile) so the `@brief` lands here in the general description of the file. Removing the `@file` would probably solve your problem.

Comment: @Albert you are correct. I'm learning doxygen and in the course of trying different things I had several rather conflicting options set.  Glad to accept an answer if you care to write it out as such.  Thanks a bunch!